# Rails DATE_FORMATS initializers causing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, initializer

I'm trying to use a technique widely reported as working on here. I would like to add a site-wide custom date format and in order to do so, I put the following lines in `config/initializers/date_formats.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
  :verbose => lambda { |time| time.strftime(
                       "%a, %b #{time.day.ordinalize}, %Y %I:%M %p") 
                     }
)
```

Note that this is the entire contents of that file. On initialization though, I get this error:

```
/whatever/config/initializers/date_formats.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions (NameError)
```

What detail am I missing?

Comment: Can you point out a link where this technique has been successfully used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Rails 3 you can just use

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(...)
```

instead of the Rails 2 format of:

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(...)
```

Comment: Thank You! That was helpful. As a follow-up: doing something like my_date.to_formatted_s(:verbose) whines if my_date is nil. So I end up doing mydate.nil? "" : mydate.to_formatted_s(:verbose). That just seems wrong, doesn't it?

Comment: First, you can just use `.to_s(:verbose)` instead of `to_formatted_s`. As far as `nil` dates/times, NilClass doesn't have a `to_formatted_s` on Nil. You could add a method to NilClass like: `def to_s(format); ""; end` to allow `nil.to_s(:verbose)` to return `""`.

Comment: You could also do `mydate.try(:to_s, :verbose) || ""`

Comment: Nice.. I like the `try or die` method :)